# Borrowed an egg from my neighbor, and found a bloodspot inside

Tags: halacha, borrowing, blood, eggs

If one borrowed an egg from a neighbor, and found a bloodspot inside, do they have to repay the egg? Should you say that since the neighbor would also throw away the egg if they found a bloodspot then one does not need to replace the egg, or do you say that since you borrowed it then you have to repay it?

Comment: [Related.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/13912)

Comment: Quite possibly relevant is that they keep roosters away from the hen coops such that some rishonim even say you can eat the bloodspot and normative Halacha as per Rav Ovadia Yosef and Rav Moshe Feinstein is that you just discard the bloodspot, not the whole egg. see here http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/broyde-1.htm

Comment: Isn't there a rule and say it is the owners mazal

Comment: Why not give back a bloody egg?

Answer (score 8):

The Shevet Halevi, [Vol. 10:133](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1420&st=&pgnum=109), was asked this question and he says that if one buys eggs which turn out to have blood spots it should be considered a מקח טעות (a mistaken purchase), but the custom is not to consider it a מקח טעות because it is impossible to determine the nature of the eggs before they are sold.

And if one borrowed eggs and some of them had blood spots, the lender cannot ask for good ones in place of the bloody ones and it might even be forbidden for the borrower to return the full amount of eggs because of ribbis (interest).

Comment: I understand it,that it is what is expected,by a store owner it is accepted that whatever you get you get,and by the the borrower you are borrowing only something which you can use and the lender will lose out.Also when you buy it is a risk,but when you borrow you need something that is usable,in essence I agree.